# Mongoose schema | creating a cooldown og maxAge property for objects in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, change-password

So i want to create a password history array.

The array will contain the users previous passwords. But at some point if the user has changed their password too much, the array will get too big and comparing hashes will take forever.

Is there any way to add a cooldown timer or maxAge to an object in the mongoose schema.
This way when a password has been stored, let's say one year, it will automatically be deleted and were all happy.

This is my mongoose schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

 ...

  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  pswHistory: {
    type: Array,
    required: false,
    default: []
  },

 ...

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema, 'user')

module.exports = User
```

Comment: i hope you do not store the password in plain text....

Comment: Thanks for your concern.. No of course not. But the hashed value of my saved passwords is saved in the database as strings. Which is why password type is set to string.

Comment: Just save the last 5 hashes...